# Dropbox sync / Google drive, how to upload sqlite database

Tags: android

I am trying to upload a sqlite database file to dropbox. This is my code:

```
public void uploadDb(){
    File public_db_file = null;
    try {
        public_db_file = writeDbToPublicDirectory();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    DbxFileSystem dbxFs = null;

    try {
        dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mAccount);
    } catch (Unauthorized e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    DbxFile testFile = null;
    try {
        testFile = dbxFs.create(new DbxPath("database_sync.txt"));
    } catch (InvalidPathException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DbxException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        testFile.writeFromExistingFile(public_db_file, false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        testFile.close();
    }

}
```

**EDIT** (More code)

This function copies my database from the app private dir to a public dir so that I can upload it:

```
private File writeDbToPublicDirectory() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File backupDB = null;
    if (sd.canWrite()) {
        String backupDBPath = "copied_database.db";
        File currentDB = context.getDatabasePath("private_database");
        backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

        if (currentDB.exists()) {
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
    }
    return backupDB;
}
```

The problem is that when I check on my device dropbox, the file size is 0 bytes. The file is created on dropbox, but my database data is not. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

I have decided that using Google Drive may be a better option, but I can only upload text files by using the sample applications. Is there any good tutorial or resource that I can use to upload a sqlite database file? I am really badly stuck on this. Please help me with either of these, thank you in advance

Comment: where (in which method) is the actual uploading do dropbox/google drivre done?

Comment: its in the testFile.writeFromExistingFile().

Comment: And you get no exceptions (you do not enter the catch clauses)?

Comment: My source file has a size and when I upload that file the size is 0 bytes. There are no executions, do you have any idea of what I could do to make this work?

Comment: If by "no executions" you mean no exceptions, than I would advise you to debug your application line by line and check if those lines return proper results. For example, check the filestreams (their lengths, whre they read from, etc.). Other than that, I have no useful suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to backup the database using Google Drive API. I have used the byte array to copy the contents. Following is the Activity code, which creates a new file on Google Drive root folder and copies the sqlite db content. I've added comments wherever required. Let me know whether it helps.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Contents;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.ContentsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFolder.DriveFileResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private GoogleApiClient api;
    private boolean mResolvingError = false;
    private DriveFile mfile;
    private static final int DIALOG_ERROR_CODE =100; 
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "person.db";
    private static final String GOOGLE_DRIVE_FILE_NAME = "sqlite_db_backup";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create the Drive API instance
        api = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE).
                addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(!mResolvingError) {
            api.connect(); // Connect the client to Google Drive
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        api.disconnect(); // Disconnect the client from Google Drive 
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Connection failed");
        if(mResolvingError) { // If already in resolution state, just return.
            return;
        } else if(result.hasResolution()) { // Error can be resolved by starting an intent with user interaction
            mResolvingError = true;
            try {
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, DIALOG_ERROR_CODE);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else { // Error cannot be resolved. Display Error Dialog stating the reason if possible.
            ErrorDialogFragment fragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("error", result.getErrorCode());
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "errordialog");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == DIALOG_ERROR_CODE) {
            mResolvingError = false;
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) { // Error was resolved, now connect to the client if not done so.
                if(!api.isConnecting() && !api.isConnected()) {
                    api.connect();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Connected successfully");

        /* Connection to Google Drive established. Now request for Contents instance, which can be used to provide file contents.
           The callback is registered for the same. */  
        Drive.DriveApi.newContents(api).setResultCallback(contentsCallback);
    }

    final private ResultCallback<ContentsResult> contentsCallback = new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Error while trying to create new file contents");
                return;
            }

            String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType("db"); 
            MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle(GOOGLE_DRIVE_FILE_NAME) // Google Drive File name
                    .setMimeType(mimeType)  
                    .setStarred(true).build();
            // create a file on root folder
            Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(api)
                    .createFile(api, changeSet, result.getContents())
                    .setResultCallback(fileCallback);   
        }

    };

    final private ResultCallback<DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveFileResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveFileResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Error while trying to create the file");
                return;
            }
            mfile = result.getDriveFile();
            mfile.openContents(api, DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY, null).setResultCallback(contentsOpenedCallback);
        }
    };

    final private ResultCallback<ContentsResult> contentsOpenedCallback = new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {

            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Error opening file");
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(getDbPath());
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
                Contents content = result.getContents();
                BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(content.getOutputStream());
                int n = 0;
                while( ( n = in.read(buffer) ) > 0 ) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }

                in.close();
                mfile.commitAndCloseContents(api, content).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status result) {
                        // Handle the response status
                    }
                });
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };

    private File getDbPath() {
        return this.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v(TAG, "Connection suspended");

    }

    public void onDialogDismissed() {
        mResolvingError = false;
    }

    public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        public ErrorDialogFragment() {}

        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            int errorCode = this.getArguments().getInt("error");
            return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this.getActivity(), DIALOG_ERROR_CODE);
        }

        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onDialogDismissed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your code and I am getting an Internal Error (Error code 8) on connection failed, when my app is trying to connect to google drive. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Manish Mulimani would you be so kind as to update this bit of code? It seems one of the methods being used here has been deprecated since `DriveFile` was updated. Specifically `commitAndCloseContents`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are a life saver!

Comment: you forget to add    BufferedOutputStream                                                   out.close();

Answer (score 3):

I modified @Manish Mulimani's code. I make use of some modules in com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo which is available from Google Drive API Website. The modules are BaseDemoActivity, ApiClientAsyncTask and EditContentsActivity. Here are the code.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;

import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFolder;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;



public class gDriveActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

    private final static String TAG = "gDriveActivity";



    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        super.onConnected(connectionHint);


        // create new contents resource.
        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
    }


    final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback =
            new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        //if failure
                        showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");
                        return;
                    }


                    //change the metadata of the file. by setting title, setMimeType.
                    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType("db");
                    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setTitle("mydb")
                            .setMimeType(mimeType)
                            .build();



                    Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                            .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, result.getDriveContents()).setResultCallback(fileCallBack);

                }

            };


    final ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallBack = new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult driveFileResult) {

            if (!driveFileResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Error while trying to create the file");
                return;
            }
            //Initialize mFile to be processed in AsyncTask
            DriveFile mfile = driveFileResult.getDriveFile();
            new EditContentsAsyncTask(gDriveActivity .this).execute(mfile);

        }
    };

    public class EditContentsAsyncTask extends ApiClientAsyncTask<DriveFile, Void, Boolean> {

        public EditContentsAsyncTask(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackgroundConnected(DriveFile... args) {
            DriveFile file = args[0];
            try {

                DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult = file.open(
                        getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY, null).await();


                if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    return false;
                }

                DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();



                //edit the outputStream
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(gDriveActivity .this);
                String inFileName = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(db.getDatabaseName()).getPath();
                FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(inFileName);
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];

                BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(driveContents.getOutputStream());
                int n = 0;
                while ((n = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
                in.close();


                com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status status =
                        driveContents.commit(getGoogleApiClient(), null).await();
                return status.getStatus().isSuccess();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException while appending to the output stream", e);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (!result) {
                showMessage("Error while editing contents");
                return;
            }
            showMessage("Successfully edited contents");
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use the Storage API

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

A useful tutorial on

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Storage_Access_Framework_Example